# What size are needed for android icons?

Tags: android, icons

I'm trying to understand what are all the various icon dimensions (in pixels) that are needed to make android apps. So far I found this site:

http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

And I see that I need (in terms of the launcher icon)

```
LDPI should be 36 x 36.

MDPI should be 48 x 48.

TVDPI should be 64 x 64.

HDPI should be 72 x 72.

XHDPI should be 96 x 96.

XXHDPI should be 144 x 144.

XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.
```

WEB - 512 x 512 (Require when upload application on Google Play).

And then I need this

```
22 × 22 area in 24 × 24 (mdpi)

33 × 33 area in 36 × 36 (hdpi)

44 × 44 area in 48 × 48 (xhdpi)

66 × 66 area in 72 × 72 (xxhdpi)

88 × 88 area in 96 × 96 (xxxhdpi)
```

These are used to represent application notifications in the status bar. They should be flat (no gradients), white and face-on perspective.

Is this missing `ldpi`? Also I don't understand why it says like 22x22 area in 24x24, what are the two dimensions mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android Notification icons are expected to have some internal padding on each edge.  That's why this guide recommends using a smaller space than the total size of the png. The padding space should be transparent.

If this guide left off ldpi, then you can compute its final size given the relative size differential between between the different densities.  [The official documentation is here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find the exact quotation

> Low-density (ldpi) resources aren’t always necessary. When you provide hdpi assets, the system scales them down by one half to properly fit ldpi screens.

It can be found at the bottom of [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)